# Attach file to email in Android Wear 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, wear-os

In my application, I'm able to write to and read from a file - either in internal or external storage. Both work for reading/writing. But, I can't attach a file from either place to an email that I'm causing to be sent (via an intent) from my app.

I've requested external storage permissions both in the manifest and at runtime in the app, and I've verified that I have them (again, I'm able to read/write from my app.) In fact everything *appears* to be working. My email client launches with the subject and email body correctly populated, and it shows that my file is attached (I get the paperclip icon by the correct file name and everything.) But, when the email is sent, the attachment gets dropped.

I'm afraid that this might just be Google/Android refusing to really allow me to pass an attachment from one app to another.

Can anybody help?

Here's the code where I'm setting up the email attachment:

```
String[] TO = {"myemail@gmail.com"};
            String[] CC = {""};
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Something cool");

            File attachment = new File(root, "TestFile2.txt");
            Uri fileUri;
            if (!attachment.exists() || !attachment.canRead()) {
                Log.d("MyMessages", "Could not find file to attach.");
            } else {
                fileUri = Uri.parse("file://" + attachment.getAbsolutePath());
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
                emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                Log.d("MyMessages", "I think I attached a file...");
            }

            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here you go...\n");

            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                finish();
                Log.d("MyMessages", "Email sent.");
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Log.d("MyMessages", "Email not sent. Client installed?");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day!
So sorry, but at this moment Wear 2.0 doesn´t support neither Intent mechanism for initiating other wear apps, nor email sending via 3-d party email client.
I have spent 3 week in searching the solution and didn't find it.